# Adding Git to /bin/bash

Tags: linux, git, bash

I have a cron and when it runs in the e-mail it states 
`/bin/bash: git command not found`

`git` works fine via terminal but how can I add it to `/bin/bash`?

Comment: Have you had a look at the excellent [crontab tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/crontab/info)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably the cron job runs under another user which has an empty profile. This means git is not in the path.

The easiest way to fix this i to use the full path to git in the cron job.

You can find the full path to git by the command:`which git`

Comment: Thanks,  will it be like this? /usr/local/git/bin/git --work-tree=/home/userName/public_html --git-dir=/home/userName/public_html/.git pull

Comment: Different computers it would be a different thing. If you want to know the full path to git on bash, you can try ```which git```.

Comment: @Edmundo , Yes that was what the answer already suggested. I think OP's comment was just trying to verify that she'd understood it all correctly.

Answer (score 0):

First, run `which git`.

Then edit you .bashrc file and add

`export PATH=$PATH:$WHICH_GIT_PATH`

Try again.